# How to prove that $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n} \le \frac{n}{n+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series $$a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n} \quad n \ge 1$$
For example, $a_3 = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}$.

I need to prove that for $n \ge 1$: 
$$a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n} \le \frac{n}{n+1}$$
I guess one could say that:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i} \le \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n}{n+1}
$$

However, I'm not sure this is rigorous enough (for example, in $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i}$ how do we really know that the index goes from $1$ to $n$) and I think this needs to be proven via induction.

So the base case is:
$$a_1 = \frac{1}{2} \le \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

The step: suppose $a_n \le \frac{n}{n+1}$ then let's prove that $$a_{n+1} \le \frac{n+1}{n+2}$$

The above can be developed as:

$$
\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{2(n+1)} \le \frac{n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}
$$

This is where I get stuck. If I could somehow prove that the number of terms to the left $\le$ the terms to the left I would be golden. Or maybe there's another way.

Comment: `I guess one could say that:` The RHS of the following inequality is wrong. It should be $\sum_{i=1}^n\cfrac{\color{red}{1}}{n+1}\,$, instead,  which is in fact equal to $\cfrac{n}{n+1}\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

You should have:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

Note that this has $1$ extra term than $a_n$ because the series is defined using $n$ twice - once for $n+1$ and again at $2n$.

From here subtract $a_n$ and rearrange to get:

$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}-\dfrac1{n+1}
+\dfrac1{2n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+2}$$

We have:

$$\dfrac1{n+1}=\dfrac2{2(n+1)}=\dfrac1{2n+2}+\dfrac1{2n+2}$$

So the extra fractions become:

$$
\begin{align}
&-\dfrac1{n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+2}\\
&=-\dfrac1{2n+2}-\dfrac1{2n+2}+\dfrac1{2n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+2}\\
&=-\dfrac1{2n+2}+\dfrac1{2n+1}\\
&=\dfrac1{2n+1}-\dfrac1{2n+2}\\
&=\dfrac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
\end{align}
$$

As $a_n \le \dfrac{n}{n+1}$ we need to prove:

$$\dfrac{n}{n+1}+\dfrac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\le\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}$$

Or equivalently that:

$$\dfrac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\le\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}-\dfrac{n}{n+1}$$

The right hand side is:

$$\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}-\dfrac{n}{n+1}=\dfrac{n^2+2n+1-n^2-2n}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

and we are done ($(n+1)(n+2)\le(2n+1)(2n+2)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: I think I understood everything except for the second transition in the second inequality, specifically how you expressed $a_{n+1}$ with $a_n$

Comment: Look at the definition of $a_n$. To get to $a_{n+1}$ we replace all instances of $n$ with $n+1$. Subtract $a_n$ from $a_{n+1}$ to get the extra terms.@Yos

Comment: Almost got it. In my rearrangement it goes like this: $a_{n+1}-a_n = \require{cancel} \cancel{\frac{1}{n+2}}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\cancel{\frac{1}{n+3}}-\cancel{\frac{1}{n+2}}+...+\frac{1}{2(n+1)} -\cancel{\frac{1}{2n}}$ so I end up with $a_{n+1}-a_n = -\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$ which is $a_{n+1} = a_n-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$ but you have an additional terms there $\frac{1}{2n+1}$. How do you get that term?

Comment: it's in the dots in the definition, $a_n$ runs from n+1 to 2n, $a_{n+1}$ runs from n+2 to 2(n+2)

Comment: so $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ belongs to $a_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Yos; exactly, because of the dots in  the definition

Comment: Also in your pre-last line $\dfrac{n^2+2n+1-n^2-2n}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ shouldn't it be $\dfrac{n^2+2n+1-n^2-2n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$?

Comment: @Yos; no, we are reducing the RHS

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$\frac{1}{n+2}< \frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$\cdots$$

$$\frac{1}{2n} < \frac{1}{n+1}$$

Now add up!

Equality comes when $n=1$.

Comment: @ user8795: that's exactly my point - how do we know that number of terms is equal on both sides of the unequality

Comment: Equality comes when n=1

Comment: I guess I didn't explain myself fully: what I mean is that the number of terms is the same (the terms need not be equal)

Comment: For example, $a_3$ is the sum of 3 terms, $a_4$ is the sum of 4 terms. But how do we really know that $a_n$ is the sum of $n$ terms?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\dfrac1{n+1}>\dfrac1{n+r}$$  for $2\le r\le n$

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee: I understand this but how do I prove that the numbers of terms on the left corresponds to the number of terms to the right of the unequality?

Comment: @Yos,  Put $r=2,\cdots,n$ and add up.

Comment: But what if $a_n$ exists which is the sum of $k$ terms such that $k \neq n$?

Answer (score 2):

Your inequality can be greatly improved. The sequence given by $a_n = H_{2n}-H_{n}$ is increasing (it is enough to compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$) hence $H_{2n}-H_n\leq \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(H_{2n}-H_n\right) = \color{red}{\log 2}$.

Answer (score 1):

One question you seem to have is:

How do we know that  $$ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n} $$ means 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i}?$$

The answer is that we don't for sure though experience suggests it does.

So if that IS the intended meaning then
here is no ambiguity to

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+i} \le  \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}.$$

Since that is what was requested, it seems that the assumed definition is correct.

But maybe something like $1/2+1/3+...+1/17$ is the sum of $1/p$ for $p$ prime in some range?

Here the final term is even and whatever the rule is should depend only on $n.$

If we think that the first term is intended to be the largest (which is reasonable but not explicit ) then at least it is valid that

$$ \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n} \quad  \le \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+...+\frac{1}{n+1}.$$